# Build error on Android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an android app but am getting an error everytime i try to build the app.

error code:

```
:app:compileDebugJava                 
C:\app\MainFragment.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
 renderView();webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("my-app");
```

my code: all code: (http://pastebin.com/iEw21Sv6)

```
renderView();

webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("my-app");


// pull to refresh
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_swipe_refresh);
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.global_bg_front_inverse, R.color.global_bg_front, R.color.global_bg_front_inverse, R.color.global_bg_front);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

// load and show data
if(mViewState==null || mViewState==ViewState.OFFLINE)
{
    loadData();
}
else if(mViewState==ViewState.CONTENT)
```

Comment: Can you post more of the class, for context please?

Comment: all code here : http://pastebin.com/iEw21Sv6

Comment: The variable webView is out of scope.

Comment: @tara123 Are you using an IDE, if the variable was out of scope, you should easily see this. Also, is there more to this error? Usually Gradle builds are pretty robust when printing out build errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `webView` variable is out of scope. In your code, do something like this instead:

```
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // restore webview state
            WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
            if(savedInstanceState!=null)
            {

                    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            }

            // setup webview
            renderView();

            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("my-app");
```